# Why doesn't my alert work?

Tags: javascript

[image]

Why doesnt my alert work? My alert is supposed to pop up when you type anything besides a number.

Comment: show code, add a plunker or jsfiddle

Comment: Try putting a semicolon after your alert, and post your code here/what you have tried so far to fix the issue.

Comment: Please don't post images of code; it's not searchable and we can't copy/paste it into answers.

Comment: the called function consists solely of `return true` so `if (!` is never satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by looking at the image of the code i can infer that the `alert` will never execute. Here is the explanation, why it is so.

When you are calling `isDitEenGetal` function with any value it is always returning `true`. This makes if condition always `false`

```
//if condition is always false
if(!isDitEenGetal(grondGetal.value)){
   alert('Dit is geen getal');
   return;
}

//always return true
function isDitEenGetal(ingave){
    return true;
}
```

This is what you need to do

```
if(!isDitEenGetal(grondGetal.value)){
   alert('Dit is geen getal');
   return;
}

//check if the value is a number or not
//return true if not a number
    function isDitEenGetal(ingave){
        return isNaN(ingave);
    }
```

Comment: Ty man, it worked :).

Comment: please accept the answer so that others can know that is really works and suits your problem.

Comment: please accept the answer so that others can know that is really works and suits your problem.

Comment: Mark it and up vote it

Answer (score 0):

Your `function isDirEenGetal(ingave)` just returns true. You simply need to check if it's a number and actually return `false` if it is not.

Try:

```
function isDirEenGetal(ingave){
     return !isNaN(ingave);
}
```

or even simpler:

```
if (isNaN(grondGetal.value)){
    alert("Hi!");
    return;
}
```